# Removing an Event Listener For Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas

I see other similar questions asked, but the answers don't actually solve the problem.

I have this event listener:

```
function bigButton(x, y, strTxt, doFunction)
{
    var getID = document.getElementById("canvas_1");

    if (getID.getContext)
    {
        var ctx = getID.getContext("2d");

        var btnW = 150;
        var btnH = 50;
        var cx = x - btnW/2;
        var cy = y - btnH/2;
        var left = cx;
        var right = cx + btnW;
        var top = cy;
        var bottom = cy + btnH;

        bbWhite(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, strTxt);

        getID.addEventListener("mousemove", function bbAnim(event)
        {   
            var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
            var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
            var mouseX = mousePos.x;
            var mouseY = mousePos.y;
            if (mouseX >= left
                && mouseX <= right
                && mouseY >= top
                && mouseY <= bottom)
            {
                bbBlack(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, strTxt);
            }
            else
            {
                bbWhite(cx, cy, btnW, btnH, strTxt);
            }

        }, false);

        getID.addEventListener("click", function bbClick(event)
        {
            var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
            var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
            var clickX = mousePos.x;
            var clickY = mousePos.y;
            if (clickX >= left
                && clickX <= right
                && clickY >= top
                && clickY <= bottom)
            {
                doFunction();
            }

        }, false);
    }
}
```

I want to remove it, because once I click it, I want to clear the canvas and do other things.  Yet I have to have a named function to remove it. As far as I know I can't have a named listener without losing all the variables used in the anonymous function. How do I have a named listener in this situation? This is one of the very first issues with events that I have come across with learning JavaScript for the canvas. I'm surprised this isn't one of the first things you find in any tutorial.

UPDATE:

I have made it into a named function, but I still have no way to remove it (and the mousemove event) after the button is clicked.

Comment: What if I don't want to remove it until later? For instance, I have a similar event for a mousemove event that I want to remove but only after the button is clicked. If I remove it in the handler for the click event, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I can't, that would ultimately be answering my own question. Also, removing it from within the handler breaks the event. It doesn't work. Trying to remove it from outside the scope of the function, it doesn't even know what I'm talking about. How do people do this?

Comment: I've updated the post with more context. If I add this.removeEventHandler("mousemove", bbClick, false); to the event function, it breaks. It no longer works. It no longer does anything when I click it. Same thing happens to the button mouseover animation.  If I try removing the eventhandlers in the doFunction() event passed, it also does not work.  I wish the JavaScript console would tell me more but it's not telling me anything at all.

Comment: I'm so confused and frustrated. The answer below has it removing the event handler from within the function. If that breaks it so that it never works to begin with, then how does that solve the problem?

Comment: See the comments in the answer below, he figured out what I was doing wrong. Removing it from within the event does break it but not if you do it after everything else it's supposed to do is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing it is pretty much the same as adding it

```
getID.addEventListener("click", handler, false);

function handler(event) {

    this.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);

    var mousePos = getMousePos(getID, event);
    var rect = getID.getBoundingClientRect();
    var clickX = mousePos.x;
    var clickY = mousePos.y;
    if (clickX >= left
        && clickX <= right
        && clickY >= top
        && clickY <= bottom)
    {
        doFunction();
    }
}
```

and the event and value of `this` stays the same wether or not you reference it by name or not.

Comment: This isn't working. The event listener is added in another function using variables from that function. left, right, top, bottom, they're all defined outside of that function.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what that other function looks like, or where the variables are coming from, you'll have to figure that out, the point is that as long as you have the element, either in getID or any other variable containing the same element, and a named reference to the bound function, which can be achieved in a number of ways, the event handler can be removed just as easily as it was added.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the variables come from though. It only matters where they're going from the point of the event. If the event names a function outside of the entire scope of the variables, then there's no way I can think of to make use of anything the event was supposed do stuff with.  Apparently I can't pass the variables along like: getID.addEventListener("click", handler(getID, left, right, top, bottom), false);

Comment: But you can place the handler function in the same scope as the anonymous function would have been? I can't for the life of me see how this would be an issue ?

Comment: I've updated my code with the full function. Maybe it will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a whole lot of sense the way you wrote it, except I put the removeEventHandler statements inside the if statement brackets after the doFunction() call. It finally works now. Thanks for your help, sorry to be so unclear at first.